# Copying console output of dd to file as well as to console

Tags: ntfs, dd, tee

I'm trying to image a hard drive using dd which is giving I/O errors. As a result I added the 'noerror' parameter, but I'd like to keep track of the errors in order to attempt recovery.

My current attempt is the following:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb bs=1M conv=sync,noerror of=output.img 2>&1 | tee output.log
```

With this, both output.img and output.log are created but both have a size of 0 bytes, and when terminating the dd no output in echoed to the terminal.

I'd prefer to try dd with the 'noerror' option before tools such as ddrescue because I'm more familiar with dd.

Also, this drive contains a single NTFS partition, so pointers on how to recover an NTFS partition with bits missing would be appreciated (the drive is 500GB and the first error I encountered was around 30GB).

Thanks!

Comment: Even if you stop `dd`, it should still generate termination messages with the records in and out and the number of bytes copied, unless you use `kill -15`.

Comment: I'm aware of that, and have just been terminating it with ^C.

Comment: Then you should have got the summary lines, unless [Attie](https://superuser.com/users/707676/attie)'s surmise is correct that `dd` never starts, though I can't reproduce a run with no output - I always get the summary lines.

Comment: You can check whether `dd` is actually running after launching the `sudo` command by typing `ps -efl | grep "dd "` in another terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly recommend that you just use [`ddrescue`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) - don't avoid a tool that is suited to the job, running it isn't hard, and you'll save yourself some stress.

Invocation is simple:

First run:

- `-p` - pre-allocate space
- `-b 4M` - use large sector size for speed

```bsh
ddrescue -p -b 4M ${SRC_DISK} ${DST_IMAGE} ${DST_LOGFILE}
```

Subsequent runs: (unlike `dd`, you can run it multiple times, and it will continue where it left off, by referring to the log file)

- `-b 512` - use a smaller sector size to try and fill in the gaps
- `-r 10` - use multiple retry passes

```
ddrescue -b 512 -r 10 ${SRC_DISK} ${DST_IMAGE} ${DST_LOGFILE}
```

Sections with read errors will (by default) contains zeroes, and you'll end up with a log file similar to below:

```
#      pos        size  status
0x00000000  0x00014E00  +
0x00014E00  0x00000200  -
0x00015000  0x00005800  +
0x0001A800  0x00000200  -
0x0001AA00  0x00028000  +
0x00042A00  0x00000200  -
0x00042C00  0x00125400  +
```

Lines marked `+` are regions that are error-free, lines marked `-` are regions with errors.

---

You might need to look into some of the following options, depending on the nature of your read errors:

```
   -d, --direct
          use direct disc access for input file

   -K, --skip-size=<min>[,<max>]
          initial size to skip on read error [64 KiB]

   -M, --retrim
          mark all failed blocks as non-trimmed

   -O, --reopen-on-error
          reopen input file after every read error

   -r, --retry-passes=<n>
          exit after <n> retry passes (-1=infinity) [0]

   -R, --reverse
          reverse the direction of all passes
```

---

In direct response to your question:

1. You're probably hitting a buffering problem... you'll likely see lots of lines appear all at once, and then nothing again - look at [`unbuffer`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unbuffer)
2. `sudo` may be asking for a password, but you redirected the prompt away... so nothing is happening.

Comment: Wouldn't the `-p` option take a long time (about a couple of hours, based on the speed I was getting with dd: about 70MB/s over USB3) to create a 500GB file on the destination drive prior to starting the rescue?

If it were a `sudo` prompt issue, wouldn't the `sudo` prompt be echoed to the terminal as well as the log file because of `tee`?

Comment: I was about to respond with "_no, because sparse files_", but then remembered that `ddrescue` will avoid making a sparse file unless instructed to do so... I'd appreciate it if you could try with / without and see what the result is!

Comment: Re `sudo` - I can't quite remember, if it's clever and re-opens the tty, then you should be fine... otherwise, it'll be redirected to stdout and then buffered in the pipe between `sudo` and `tee` until the buffer is full enough to be written out... so possibly not.